# Replacing $q^2$ by $q$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, terminology, power-series

I have a rather strange question. Suppose we are given a formal power series
$$S(q^2) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n q^{2n}.$$
I wish to replace $q^2$ by $q$. This implies that $S(q) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n q^n$. For example, replacing $q^2$ by $q$ in
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n^2 q^{2n} = \frac{q^2 (1 + q^2)}{(1 - q^2)^3}, \quad |q| < 1$$
leads to
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n^2 q^n = \frac{q (1 + q)}{(1 - q)^3}, \quad |q| < 1.$$

My question is: How do I make the statement "replace $q^2$ by $q$" precise and mathematically sound? I think replacing $q^2$ to $q$ is a valid operation. But, apparently, saying "replace $q^2$ by $q$" is ambiguous because if $f$ and $g$ are some arbitrary functions, then, in general, $f(q^2) = g(q^2)$ does not imply $f(q) = g(q)$.

Comment: I suppose you could say "compose $S$ with the square root function"; if $f$ and $g$ are functions on the positive reals and $f=g$, it follows that $f\circ h = g\circ h$, where $h(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: If $S(q) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n q^{n}$ holds for any $q \in \mathbb R$, it holds for $q = \sqrt 2$ as well.

Comment: @mirgee $\sqrt{2}$? Note: $|q| < 1$. Please read the question. This does not really answer my question.